# How to launch a dispatch after the previous ends

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

First of all, give thanks for reading my question and try to help me and apologize for my English.

I'm using redux and redux-thunk and I would like to launch multiple dispatchs on redux. To be more precise, I would like launch a dispatch after previous one ends.

My proble is that I dont know how make it without a fetch.

For example:
launch dispatch1 -> ends dispatch1 -> launch dispatch2

Here is my code:

```
static moveLayer(layerSelected, direction) {
    const mapLayers = [... AxisStore.getStore().getState().map.mapGLlayers];
    const ids = mapLayers.map(l => l.id);
    const index = ids.indexOf(layerSelected.id);
    let newIndex = direction === 'down' ? index - 1 : index + 1;

    let layerUpdated = Object.assign({}, mapLayers[index], {
        redraw: false
    });
    let oldPositionLayer = Object.assign({}, mapLayers[newIndex], {
        redraw: false
    });

    if (direction === 'down') {
        mapLayers.splice(newIndex, 2, layerUpdated, oldPositionLayer);
    } else {
        mapLayers.splice(index, 2, oldPositionLayer, layerUpdated);
    }

    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({
            type: MapTypeConstants.SET_MAP_LAYERS,
            payload: mapLayers
        });
    };
}

static updateBefore(layer) {
    let mapLayers = [... AxisStore.getStore().getState().map.mapGLlayers];
    const ids = mapLayers.map(l => l.id);
    const posInRedux = ids.indexOf(layer.id);
    let nextVisibleLayer = mapLayers.find((layerObj, idx) => idx > posInRedux && layerObj.layout && layerObj.layout.visibility && layerObj.layout.visibility === 'visible');
    mapLayers[posInRedux].before = (nextVisibleLayer) ? String(nextVisibleLayer.id) : undefined;
    mapLayers[posInRedux].redraw = (mapLayers[posInRedux].layout.visibility === 'visible') ? true : false;
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({
            type: MapTypeConstants.SET_MAP_LAYERS,
            payload: mapLayers
        });
    };
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To wait for an async call to end, you can use the JS keyword `await`. When using this keyword, you code will pause until the Promise you called has ended, your function will now need to become `async` too :

```
myFunction = async () => {
    await dispatch({})
    dispatch({})
}
```

You second dispatch will not be called unless the first one has finished.

**That's your only way, see the comment below**

A second option is to use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). It will execute an array of Promises in the order that you submitted them :

```
myFunction = async () => {
    await Promises.all([
        dispatch({}),
        dispatch({})
    ])
}
```

Comment: `Promises.all` does execute promises in parallel, not sequentially !

Answer (score 0):

You can try [redux-loop](https://github.com/redux-loop/redux-loop), which does exactly what you were asking for.

> A port of the Elm Architecture to Redux that allows you to sequence your effects naturally and purely by returning them from your reducers.